# how to create a read/write folder under asset?

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE 2.1.2 (native SDK).

I created a folder that I named "**server**" under "**assets/images/**" folder where I will save the downladed images from server.

For a reason I don't know, when I run my app. using the IDE it works perfectly but when I use the release app (.bar) and install it manually, it doesn't work because the assets forlder is in read-only mode according to this [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/device_platform/data_access/file_system.html).

I don't get it !! normally the forlder "**server**" should be in read/write mode and I need it to be under assets folder because I will use these images and set them in ***ImageViews*** using the relative path ("**assets:///**").

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Don’t know about BB10’s conventions, but reading the page you linked it seems pretty clear that assets is read-only and that you should write to data/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Frank said, `assests` are read only. Use `data` folder.

For some reason assets *may be* read-write in a debug mode, but never as a release.

**Edit**: access data from c++:

```
QString path = QString(QDir::homePath() + "/images");
```

which will go to /data/images

Comment: Actually that's what I did : I saved the images under data and it works. But the problem is that when I try to set one of these images in an imageview normally I should use an absolute path like "assets:///" which in this case should be "data:///" but it is not working (I need to set the image using c++ not qml).

Comment: I added path to data folder

Comment: sorry to be late. but it is not working ; I tried to set like : Image img = Image(QUrl("data/image.png")). Also for a reason I don't know "QDir::homePath()" and "QDir::currentPath()" are not working in release mode.

Comment: Maybe you're missing /(slash)? Try printing path out and paste it here

Comment: ok ! Actually I created a folder under "data" that I named "images". so When I try to set an Imageview with an image like I said before I use : Image img = Image(QUrl("./data/images/imageName.png")); imgView.setImage(img);

Comment: It is working !! sorry my bad, I was putting "QDir::homePath()+/data/" it was really stupid I didn't know "homePath" returns the app's directory work path (../data/). Thx a lot !!